# all users are posting to the same twitter account instead of their own (rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-oauth

I'm stuck on the last step of the Twitter gem implementation and I have everything working. 
Except, when users post, everything is getting sent to the same one Twitter account.

There are users who are not authenticated using omniauth and some are. 
At the moment, there is only 1 entry in the Authentications table and everything is getting posted through this to the same Twitter account.

Here's the code

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def create
    twitter.update(@post.content)
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

Here's how "twitter" is defined in my Application Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
def twitter
    unless @twitter_user
      provider = Authentication.find_by_provider('twitter')
      @twitter_user = Twitter::Client.new(:oauth_token => provider.token, :oauth_token_secret => provider.secret) rescue nil
    end
    @twitter_user
  end
```

How can I make the `twitter.update(@post.content)` only happen for those authenticated through omniauth and make sure any posts sent to Twitter are sent to the correct account given the codes above?

Answer (score 0):

```
provider = Authentication.find_by_provider('twitter')
```

You're pulling out the Twitter authentication information based on just the provider being 'twitter'. If you wish to post to an account tied to a particular user, you need to *fetch the twitter credentials based on something that uniquely identifies the user*.

I don't know your exact model scheme, but in pseudocode it might look something like this:

```
provider = Authentication.find_by_email(current_user.email)
```

or

```
provider = Authentication.find_by_handle(current_user.handle)
```